# Using Javascript In Dynamically Embeded HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

How do you use, or correctly use, javascript in dynamically embedded pages/content?

When an event occurrs I am loading a PHP/HTML page into an HTML element. The javascript works fine on the outter page, or the page that the content gets loaded into, but it does not work on the page that is being loaded.

Here is my request function:

```
function sendServiceRequest(file, nvpSendData, successCallback, failCallback) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: file,
        data: nvpSendData,
        dataType: 'html'
    }).success(function(data, status) {
        console.log(".done");
        console.log("Return AJAX status: " + status);
        //console.log("success data: " + JSON.stringify(data));
        successCallback(data, status);
    }).fail(function(data, status, error) {
        console.log(".fail");
        console.log("Return AJAX status: " + status);
        //console.log("Return data: " + JSON.stringify(data));
        failCallback(data, status, error);
    });
}
```

Then i have a php page, *viewScripts.php*, that has this javascript file included, that handles the loading process

view_events.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var rx = document.querySelector("#rx-number").value;
    sendServiceRequest(
        "/comments/get_content.php",
        {action:"loadContent", loadType:"comments", rx_number:rx},
        function(data, status) {
            document.querySelector("#rx-comments-container").innerHTML = data;
        },
        function(data, status, error) {
            console.log("AJAX send service request failed while loading comments!");
        }
    );
});
```

Then in the code above, */comments/get_content.php* verifies the data being sent, and then loads the page *comment.php* into a div element, *#rx-comments-container*. Up until this point everything is fine. It's the javascript in *comment.php* that does not want to work. I have tried including a '.js' file with the specified functions to handle events into *comment.php*, but this does not work. I have also tried including the event functions in *view_events.js*, as listed above, which is included in *viewScripts.php*, and this does not want to work either. I have also tried embedding the javascript directly into *comments.php*, but this doesn't work either.

Here is the javascript that is to be included in *comments.php*:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("edit-rx-comment-glyph").addEventListener("click", function () {
        var id = this.value;
        sendServiceRequest(
            "/comments/get_content.php",
            {action: "loadContent", loadType: "editComment", comment_id: id},
            function (data, status) {
                document.querySelector('#' + id).innerHTML = data;
            },
            function (data, status, error) {
                console.log("AJAX send service request failed while loading edit form!");
            }
        );
    });

    document.getElementsByClassName("comment-history-glyph").addEventListener("click", function () {
        var id = this.value;
        sendServiceRequest(
            "/comments/get_content.php",
            {action: "loadContent", loadType: "viewHistory", comment_id: id},
            function (data, status) {
                document.querySelector('#comments-body').innerHTML = data;
            },
            function (data, status, error) {
                console.log("AJAX send service request failed while loading edit form!");
            }
        );
    });
});
```

Comment: When PHP generates HTML, the final document arrives in the browser no differently than if it was static HTML.  Your dynamic HTML can contain any valid JavaScript in any part of it.  Have you verified that the JavaScript included in comments.php is valid and works?  Do you get any error messages in your browser's console?

Comment: Is the `DOMContentLoaded` event not be fired a second time?

Comment: You already went so far as to use jQuery for your AJAX call. Why not go all the way and use jQuery to get elements by ID and class name as well?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure this out. I guess i was doing something wrong, because my code ended up working. I just used an onclick event with the sendServiceRequest function, and that ended up working. I didn't need to include any other js files.